# Pyridine synthesis by tin(II) chloride reduction of 5-nitronorbornene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, heterocyclic-compounds

What is the reaction mechanism here?

I guess the $\ce{SnCl2}$ reduces $\ce{NO2}$ to $\ce{NH2}$ but then what happens?

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking there is a retro-Diels-Alder in there somewhere

Comment: Can you please show me how exactly, I tried didn’t work

Comment: If I knew exactly I would post an answer. I do not have database access to find the paper where this is reported.

Comment: @Waylander A side-note about the speculated occurrence of a retro-DA, I'm sceptical; because in the starting material, I count 12, but in the product only 11 carbon atoms.

Comment: @Buttonwood Count again! There are 13 in the SM

Comment: @Waylander Agreed, I forgot the bridge.  A difference of two C like for ethene, maybe.

Answer (score 10):

This reaction was conducted by [Ho and Liao<sup>1</sup>](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403900767992). Nitro compound **1** is reduced to the nitroso compound **2** which undergoes a [3+3] electrocyclization to form **3** (**4**). Tautomerization of **4** to **5** is followed by a retro-"Diels-Alder" reaction to open to **6**. Conjugate addition of the nitrogen to the unsaturated aldehyde moiety of **6** to afford dihydro pyridine **7**. Tautomerization of **7** to **8** is followed by the loss of acetaldehyde. [Structures are from the paper; my numbering.]
[image]
**ADDENDUM:** The mechanism provided in the paper does not address a number of stereochemical issues. Nitro compound **1** is obviously formed as an *endo*-Diels-Alder product between (*E*)-(2-nitrovinyl)benzene and 1,3-cyclopentadiene. The bicyclic compound **3** (**4**) must have a *cis*-fusion given the mechanism of the [3+3]-electrocyclization (**2** → **3**) (*vide infra*). However, the stereochemistry arising from the *retro*-Diels-Alder reaction would not be expected to kinetically form the (*Z,Z*)-diene **6** but rather the (*E,Z*)-isomer **6a**. Clearly, **6a** is incapable of cyclization as prescribed. But **6a** is a masked, vinylogous malonaldehyde that is susceptible to enolization and isomerization to **6b** or **6c**. While **6c** can cyclize by the reported procedure of conjugate addition, there is also the probability that ring closure occurs by electrocyclization of **6b**.

[image]

1. Tse-Lok Ho and Po-Yau Liao, [*Tetrahedron Lett*., **1994**, *35*, 2211](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403900767992). DOI:10.1016/S0040-4039(00)76799-2

Comment: I already upvoted your answer. But I'm curious about the elimination of acetaldehyde. What is the driving force? Is that mean $\beta$-amino acids are prone to leave $\ce{CO2}$?

Comment: @Mathew: 
Wouldn't be surprised if the zwitterion of beta-aminopropionic acid gives ethylene under some set of conditions. In the present case, becoming aromatic is certainly worth something. If you mix 9 and 10 under some set of conditions, I'd be surprised to see any 8.

Comment: @Mathew: I've thinking about your question again. There are stannic salts generated in the reduction. Perhaps they facilitate loss of acetaldehyde. So the question is, will Sn(IV) catalyze the addition of acetaldehyde to 3-phenylpyridine (9) to form 8?

Comment: Might not. Otherwise, the last elimination step would have been reversible. I think gaining aromatically is a very good point for the elimination. In my experience, I didn't find any decomposition of $\beta$-amino acids during their synthesis.

Comment: Mostly a quibble, but I was wondering if the last step could be conveniently drawn as such. A bit reminiscent of beta-ketoacid decarboxylation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byn29.jpg (cc @MathewMahindaratne)

Comment: @orthocresol: Good point. Done

Comment: @orthocresol: Good point. Why I didn't think thay before? Now, I don't have any doubts.